# Jquery.text() have changed but text in <div> not change in recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a recursive Function to read data and have some code Jquery in that function.
My data:

```
const data = {
    name: "Quotes"
    children: [
        { 
             name: "Quotes/Quote - Quote 1 - 1",
             children: [],
             ....
        }, 
        { 
             name: "Quotes/Quote",
             children: [{..}, {...}, ...],
             ....
        },
        { 
             name: "Body",
             children: [{..}],
             ....
        },
        ...
    ],
    .....
}
```

My Code:

```
// index.html
<div id="label">Start parse data ...</div>

// index.js
function parseData(data) {
     $('#label').text(data.name);
     console.log(data.name);  //  I put console to track data

     ...... // my code to process
     
     if (data.children.length) {
          for (const childrenData of data.children) {
               parseData(childrenData);
          }
     }
    
     
}

const data = $.ajax(.....)  // data return from ajax is above,

parseData(data);

$('#label').text("==== Done ====");
```

The result, my  text is "Start parse data ...", after few second, it change to "==== Done ====". My expectation is it change to data.name during parseData().

I have track my recursive function by console.log() and data is working fine.
[image]

I have searched on Internet and somebody said that put into `setTimeout()`, but it is NOT still working

```
setTimeout(() => $('#label').text(data.name), 0);
```

Comment: Use a non-zero timeout in the setTimeout call e.g. setTimeout(() => $('#label').text(data.name), 1000); for 1s delay.

You could also try using the browser dev tools and adding a breakpoint inside parseData so that it stops inside each time it runs. You should be able to see it change the value every time it stops at the breakpoint.

If you're just replacing the content every time it parses something, does it really matter if the value its parsing is shown if it's just going to get replaced by the 'DONE' text when everything's finished anyway?

Comment: You also might be dealing with the single-threaded nature of JS.  Between the beginning call to `parseData()` and the end of `$('#label').text("==== Done ====")` it's likely that there's no break taken to repaint the screen.  So, although the value is actually set in the underlying DOM, you simply don't see it yet on the screen.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you 'r right, I also saw `$('#label').text()` have changed in DOM, but it not repainted on screen. Do you have any solution to resolve it ?

Comment: If you really need to see these otherwise brief changes, you would have to find a way to add some delay in there, presumably with a `setTimeout`, but the recursive nature means that the most simple ways of doing so won't work.  It also means that you would have no idea how long the full cycle would take...